# Switching Application1 to Application2. Successfully switched to Application2, but click operations are not performing on Application2

Tags: appium, appium-android

> My appium version is 1.9.0 and java client is 1.6.0 and android sdk 27.

Here is my sample code of hybrid application. My app1 and app2 have same button i.e `signin` and id for that both button is same.
but if trying click on app2 signin button it was clicked on app1 `signin` `button`.

```
public class sample {
    AndroidDriver driver;   
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "xyz");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.app1.pkgname");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.app1.activityname");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        // provide implicit wait
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test() {    
        Activity activity = new Activity("com.app2.pkgname", "com.app2.MainActivityName");
        activity.setStopApp(true);
        ((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(activity);

        System.out.println("current context it will return native "+((AndroidDriver) driver).getContext()); 

        ((AndroidDriver) driver).context("WEBVIEW_com.app2");

        WebElement xx = driver.findElement(By.id("SA_btn_SignIn"));
        xx.isEnabled();   // returning true
        xx.click(); // but not get click on element of app2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

> Make sure you are using Java client 6.1.0 and not 1.6.0

First, you need to use generics with AndroidDriver, like,

```
AndroidDriver <AndroidElement>
```

So your code should look like,

```
public class sample {
  AndroidDriver <AndroidElement> driver;
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "xyz");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.app1.pkgname");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.app1.activityname");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);
    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
    try {
      driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void Test() {
    Activity activity = new Activity("com.app2.pkgname", "com.app2.MainActivityName");
    activity.setStopApp(true);
    driver.startActivity(activity);
    System.out.println("current context it will return native " + driver.getContext());
    driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.app2");
    AndroidElement xx = driver.findElement(By.id("SA_btn_SignIn"));
    if (xx.isEnabled()) {
      AndroidTouchAction action = new AndroidTouchAction (driver);
      action.tap(TapOptions.tapOptions().withElement(ElementOption.element(xx))).perform();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Wasiq Bhamla above solution is working in native view if i comment driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.app2") it worked fine;  but for hybrid view above solution not worked. please let mi know any solution for hybrid view regarding it

Comment: Can you check which context is currently used before you call context line. Use driver.getContext () which will return 'NATIVE_APP' when on native app else 'WEBVIEW_1' when on web view. Let me know if this works.